# Making http.get on page from observable in provider in Angular2/Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic2, observable

Im having some trouble migrating my Ionic app (Angular > Angular2) mostly with promises/observables.

This is my method on the **CartPage**:

```
this.cartService.list().subscribe(
data => {
    console.log(data);
    this.cartData = data.cart;
err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

And in the **cart provider**:

```
list() {

    this.storage.get('token')
    .then((token) => {

        var authHeader = new Headers();
        authHeader.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + JSON.stringify(token).replace(/['"]+/g, ''));

        this.http.get(this.global.getApiUrl()+'cart/list', {
            headers: authHeader
        })
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.data = data.data;
                return this.data;
            },
            err => {
                console.log(err);
            }
        );

    });

}
```

But i get:

Typescript Error
Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.

---

So i've searched and searched and haven't found either in docs or in examples/tutorials an observable used like this that worked.

I dont know if im missing declaring the type somehow or if i shoulnd't use subscribe and use some different method.

Thanks!

Comment: you should resolve your `this.storage.get('token')` first, then you should return `this.http.get(...).map(...)`, the `subscriber` is like the `then` of the promises, but you must provide a `subscriber`, if not the observable won't be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Cart page:

```
   this.cartService.list(token).subscribe(
      data => {
         console.log(data);
         this.cartData = data.cart;
      err => {
         console.log(err);
      });
```

Cart provider:

```
   list(token) {
      var authHeader = new Headers();
      authHeader.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + JSON.stringify(token).replace(/['"]+/g, ''));

      return this.http.get(this.global.getApiUrl()+'cart/list', {
          headers: authHeader
      })
      .map(res => res.json());

   }
```

Well this is a race condition, main issue here is that you need the **token** for the **http request** but you must get that information from the `Storage`and that operation is **async**.

Find a way to get the token before the list call.
The easiest way is to have a Provider to hold that data and use it as a proxy to the ionic `Storage` provider, so when the provider starts it run something like a `init()` and gets the basic data needed for your app, like the **token** and other stuffs, then you just inject that provider on your `CartProvider` and call `myDataProvider.token`.